OpenGL program is showing black screen only, while it should be showing a square

Nothing is drawn in the screen.
Only a black window is being shown and no shape or anything.
My laptop doesn't have a dedicated Graphics card, only the integrated one. But it was working fine in same device some days ago.

Here is my main.cpp
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include"stb_image.h"
#include<GL/glew.h> // It links from the driver to the opengl function pointers
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<glm/glm.hpp>
#include<glm/vec2.hpp>
#include<glm/vec3.hpp>
#include<glm/vec4.hpp>
#include<glm/mat4x4.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include<SOIL2/SOIL2.h>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>

#define GLEW_STATIC

struct Vertex{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 color;
    glm::vec2 texcoord;
};


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height){ // For the resizeability
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

float vertices[] = {
        // positions          // colors           // texture coords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
    };
unsigned int indices[] = {  
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3 // second triangle
};

unsigned nofVertices = sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(Vertex); // WIll work here, but if I am sending it to a function and then recienving a pointer then sizeof() will take the size of the pointer and will give errors.


unsigned nofIndices = sizeof(indices)/sizeof(GLuint);







/// Handling Input. This one is currently just closes the window at esc.
void updateInput(GLFWwindow* window){
    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS){
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }
}

// Loading shaders:
bool loadshaders(GLuint &program){
    bool flag = true;
    char infoLog[512];
    GLint success;
    // glsl ig compiles ie links in runtime.

    std::string temp="";
    std::string src="";

    std::ifstream in_file;

    in_file.open("vertex_core.glsl");

    if(in_file.is_open()){
        while(std::getline(in_file, temp)){
            src+=temp+'\n';
        }
    }
    else{
        flag=false;
        std::cout<<"ERROR::LOADSHADERS::COULDNOT_OPEN_THE_FILE\n";
    }

    in_file.close();

    // createing a vertex shader.
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); // id of vertex shader beign created in the background, of gl memory. 

    // setting a source to the shader;
    const GLchar* vertexSRC = src.c_str();

    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSRC, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader); //  compiles the shader from source.
    
    // checking any compile error:
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if(!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout<<"ERROR: "<<infoLog<<"\n";
    }

    temp="";
    src="";



    // Making a fragment:
    in_file.open("fragment_core.glsl");

    if(in_file.is_open()){
        while(std::getline(in_file, temp)){
            src+=temp+'\n';
        }
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<"ERROR::LOADSHADERS::COULDNOT_OPEN_THE_FILE\n";
    }

    in_file.close();

    // createing a vertex shader.
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER ); // id of vertex shader beign created in the background, of gl memory. 

    // setting a source to the shader;
    const GLchar* fragSRC = src.c_str();

    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragSRC, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader); //  compiles the shader from source.
    
    // checking any compile error:
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if(!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout<<"ERROR: "<<infoLog<<"\n";
    }


    // Program
    // attaching shaders to a program:
    program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

    glLinkProgram(program);

    glGetProgramiv(program,GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

    // error handling:
    if(!success){
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout<<infoLog<<std::endl;
    }

    // End: resets everything
    glUseProgram(0);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    return flag;
}

GLuint Texture; // Make this global or return it from function

void setTexture() {
    glGenTextures(1, &Texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
    
    // Settings
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Load image
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);  // Add this
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("sumner-mahaffey-7Y0NshQLohk-unsplash.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (!data) {
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
    if (data) {
        std::cout << "Channels: " << nrChannels << std::endl;
        GLenum format = (nrChannels == 4) ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB;
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
}



int main(){
    // GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow();
    glfwInit(); // initializing the glfw
   
    // ! Consts
    const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 640;
    const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;
    // framebuff can be diff that window
    int frame_buff_width = 0; // Its the canvas that been strecthed to fit the frame.
    int frame_buff_height = 0; 

    // To set some options to OPENGL.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);  // this one sets the version of opengl to use.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); // To use the modern version of the core functions.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    // glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); for Mac

    // Create Window
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "My window", NULL, NULL);

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &frame_buff_width, &frame_buff_height); // To set the Frame buffer size

    // set Viewport: how much  window we are drawing on
    glViewport(0,0,frame_buff_width,frame_buff_height); // Canvas size

    // Set Context to the window for glew and all libs.
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // ! Very Important.


    // Init GLEW (It needs a window and openGL context to properly run)
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; // to use modern opengl functionalities.

    // Check glew Init
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        std::cout<<"ERROR::openGL_init.cpp::GLEW_INIT_FAILED\n";
        glfwTerminate();
    }


    // Some OpenGL options:
    // As openGL is a state machine. we can enable some setting that are always running in the background

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // This lets us draw depth

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); // This helps us in such a way that if something is blocked some some other obj it dont get rendered at all.

    glCullFace(GL_BACK); // Telling what not to render. ie the backside.
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW); // counter clock wise

    glEnable(GL_BLEND); // enable the blending of colors etc.
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); // doing setting of the blend.

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL); // LINE for jus lines. fill for filling

    // Shader Initialization
    GLuint core_program;
    loadshaders(core_program);

    // MODEL
    
    // sending vertices/data to the shaders
    
    // VAO, VBO. EBO
    // vertex Aarray object. Id for the whole model
    // Vertex buffer object. sends vertex info to GC.
    // Vertex element object. sends indices data to the GC.

    // Generating VAO and Binding
    GLuint VAO;
    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &VAO); // We kind of created a shell to use.
    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // binding it to the variable

    // Generating VBO and sending Data
    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO); // genertating the buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); // 1st: array buffer tells the type of buffer kind of
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  // static draw cause we don't want to change the drawing often. use other enums for dynamic usage

    // Generating VEO and sending Data
    GLuint EBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO); // genertating the buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  // static draw cause we don't want to change the drawing often. use other enums for dynamic usage

    // We don't wnat to send data again. as sending mem from cpu to gpu is expensive.

    // seting VertexAttribute pointer and enable some options (input assembly)
    // GLuint attribLoc = glGetAttribLocation(core_program, "vertex_position"); /// Can give the index like this way also
    
    // Position
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Color
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // TextureCoord
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    // Bind VAO 0
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    setTexture();
    glUseProgram(core_program);
    GLint texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(core_program, "OurTexture");
    if (texLoc == -1) {
        std::cout << "Failed to find uniform location for 'OurTexture'" << std::endl;
    } else {
        glUniform1i(texLoc, 0); // Ensure this is done after glUseProgram
    }
    

    // glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "texture1"), 0);
    // Main loop
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        GLenum err;
        while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << "OpenGL error: " << err << std::endl;
        }

        /// setting resizing of window. (Currently not working)
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
        // Log runtime information
        // std::cout << "Frame buffer size: " << frame_buff_width << "x" << frame_buff_height << std::endl;
        // std::cout << "Window size: " << WINDOW_WIDTH << "x" << WINDOW_HEIGHT << std::endl;
        // std::cout << "Number of vertices: " << nofVertices << std::endl;
        // std::cout << "Number of indices: " << nofIndices << std::endl;

        // update Input --
        glfwPollEvents();

        // update
        updateInput(window);


        // draw
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
        // clear
        glClearColor(0.f,0.f,0.f,1.f); // R,G,B,alpha
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT); // uses to clear buffers. Here we are clearing color buff.

        // use a program
        glUseProgram(core_program);

        
        // Bind Vertex array object. know where our data is
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        // draw
        // glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, nofIndices ); 
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, nofIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // Change the fragment shader for the final texture of the drawing. eg I can change the color of triangle by just changining it to not get the index data but hardcoded values.

        // Vertex shader runs for no. verteces and fragment runs vertex shader. Total here they both run 3,3 times.

        // end draw
        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap and 
        glFlush(); // flush
    }

    // End
    glfwTerminate(); // to free up the memory etc.

    // delet program
    glDeleteProgram(core_program);
}

here is my fragment_core.glsl:
#version 440 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D OurTexture;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(OurTexture, TexCoord) * vec4(ourColor, 1.0);
}

here is my vertex_core.glsl:
#version 440 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}

Here is the Picture of what issue I am facing:
When I a m running the code, Its just a black window


The first thing to do is add some error checking https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error

'The texture is not being loaded' Probably because the directory that your program is looking for the texture is different from the directory where the texture file exists. Where is the texture file and why do you think the program is going to look there?

Are  you running from a terminal where you can see the std::couts that you have in the code?

@drescherjm Yes, I am running it in fedora linux. I am using g++.

@AlanBirtles
I have added the picture of the issue I am facing. Sorry for earlier misunderstanding. The code that I am running in the picture (./Squares) was running fine a few days ago but now no code is working. Not even a simple Triangle is being shown now.

If the code worked a few days ago but doesn't now, that's when you fire up git bisect.

Both of the triangles in your vertex geometry:
float vertices[] = {
    // positions          // colors           // texture coords
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, // top left
};

unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3, // second triangle
};

...are wound clockwise.
And since you asked OpenGL to cull those:
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);

...neither triangle will be drawn.
You have multiple options:

Disable face culling via glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)
Switch to culling front-facing triangles via glCullFace(GL_FRONT)
Switch to culling counter-clockwise wound triangles via glFrontFace(GL_CW)
Re-do the indices so the triangles are wound counter-clockwise
Re-do the vertex positions so the triangles the indices specify are wound counter-clockwise

